# Fastest way to select the next record in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a faster or more efficient way to select the next record than this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID > @LastIDRead 
ORDER BY ID
```

*Note: I need all the columns*

Comment: Is `ID` your Clustered Index?

Comment: Yes ID is clustered index and no, there is no cursor involve here.

Comment: Does SQL server short-circuit the ORDER BY, so it only gets one row from the index?  Or does it have to read the full index?  I just answered my own question . . . It does seem to shortcircuit the order by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the fastest way if you have a CLUSTERED INDEX on ID.

Answer (score 0):

the "next record" is irrelevant here, what you want is to get a record based on its ID. If the Id is indexed, that would be the best option.

Comment: Based on the query I provided, how will you interpret it? Is it not selecting the next record?

Comment: yes but what I meant is that the "next" word doesnt matter, what you are doing is looking for a specific row, so doing WHERE ID = LastIDRead and passig LastIDRead asn the current ID + 1 would be the same

Comment: The problem with + 1 is that when there is a gap (e.g. deleted records)